# Where in the world should I look for a software job?

Tags: job-hunting

I am a Canadian Software Engineer. I want to work overseas (outside North America) years starting next Summer.

My limitations:

- **Non-permanent:** I'd like to work overseas for 1-2 years. I'm worried this will limit my employability.
- **English-only:** I know a little French and Spanish but I definitely not enough to work in those languages.
- **Junior Experience:** I am confident in my ability to code but I only have two years of work experience.

Is there anyone else here who has made a similar move? If so, where?

Answer (score 2):

If you are aged 18-35 you can work in the following countries pretty easily up to 1 year.

http://www.international.gc.ca/experience/destinations_out-destinations_sortant.aspx?lang=eng

Look for contract positions online, maybe in Ireland or UK where there is a good demand for IT professional and be clear in your CV that you qualify for this kind of VISA.

If you are older, you may need other types of VISA, and it's more difficult that a company would sponsor you for just a year or two.

Another solution could be to become a [*digital nomad*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_nomad), you will work remotely online, but you will still need to find a company that offer you this king of contract, or looking for work online as a contractor/freelance.
You will continue to need a VISA to enter in some countries, but since you will not need to looking for a job there, may it could be easier to obtain. You will also need to get some advises regarding taxes since you will need to comply with more than one tax legislation and at least one bilater tax agreement.